# iOS 9 Beta 5 made my app not work

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, ios9

I am relatively new to iOS coding, and swift. I have only coded in Swift, and not Swift 2. I am nervous that updating to the latest XCode will delete my files, or do something crazy, because that has happened before, so I have kept the last version, Xcode 6.3 (i think). Now, when I test my applications on my iPhone 6 with the iOS 9 Beta 5 software, most of my tableviews are not showing anything in them. They load the correct amount of rows, but they are not displaying anything.

1. How should I go about fixing this?
2. Should I update to Xcode 7?
3. If I do, will I have to change the code, and will my apps then still be able to be used on previous iOS operating systems? In other words, will there be a transition from Swift to Swift 2?

Comment: You can do it, you do it with a lot of apps, remember when iphone 6 just came up, a lot of apps weren't yet prepared for it and you could open them anyway. @matt

Comment: @matt It's common and normal to test an existing app as-is using non-beta Xcode on a device with the next iOS in beta. This allows someone to see if their app works as-is with the newest iOS without the need (if desired) to use the latest tools or update code for updated APIs. Sometimes a person's schedule doesn't allow for the transition right away. Sometime you just want to make sure your existing app works.

Comment: @matt Where are you seeing anything about iOS 6 or even iOS 7? The OP seems to be asking about an iOS 8/Swift app that isn't working properly on a device with iOS 9b5. It is normal and common to test an iOS 8 app on an iOS 9b5 device. And it's normal to see things break in such a situation. And if the OP doesn't yet want to upgrade their project to Xcode 7 and Swift 2 there is nothing wrong with trying to make the existing iOS 8/Swift/Xcode 6 app work as-is under iOS 9.

Comment: @matt If I knew you meant iOS 8 and 9 instead of 6 and 7 I wouldn't have replied. BTW - I do what the OP is trying to do every year. To me it is perfectly normal. This way I can put out an update to my existing app that will work on the new version of iOS without the need to update everything. This allows me to work on a proper update with new features for the new version of iOS on my own schedule knowing my existing app  will work for existing users that update their iOS version. To each his own.

Comment: Before you update any software make sure you have good backups.

Answer (score 0):

There will be a transition, for sure. That doesn't mean it won't work. My suggestion is to download Xcode 7 beta, make a backup of your original project and open it with Xcode 7 beta.

Comment: Is it possible to have both Xcode 6 and Xcode 7? What will the transition entail? Is there different syntax for everything? Also, if I transition it to Xcode 7, and then submit that app to the app store, will it still work on iOS 8 devices even though it is compiled for iOS 9? Sorry I don't know much about compiling / beta relationships.

Comment: Xcode 7 is in beta so you will have Xcode and Xcode beta as 2 separate apps in your mac

Comment: There is different syntax between swift 1.2 and 2, and, you can set the minimum iOS version it will support

Comment: Okay, so then my next question is: Can I submit apps to the app store from the Xcode 7 beta? And then those will work on all previous devices (which i set)?

Comment: Yes, you can set which iOS version is the minimum supported version

Comment: So, I updated to the Xcode 7 beta, and it converted it. i had about 50 errors afterwards, mostly relating to Parse. Some weren't, and I haven't figured out how to fix them. But now, i'm having a problem with my first view controller. I have an if statement... if true, go to one screen, false, go to another. The performSegueWithIdentifier function works with one of the segue identifiers, and not the other one. Do you have any idea why this could be? I can't even get into the app now... this is what I was worried about.

Comment: Check in the storyboard if the segues are still there and if they still have their identifiers

Comment: They are still there and still have their identifiers. I checked with another segue to a diff view, and that works. It is only this one view that is not moving from... I am very confused. I cleaned the project, I deleted and re added the segue. I don't know what else to do.